# getline() compiles without std::

Tags: c++, string, getline

I did some code and found that getline() compiles without std:: namespace.

How this work? Is it because C function getline() ?

Here is example code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string s;
    getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

Comment: `What is “Argument-Dependent Lookup”` does not answer the question.

Comment: Have you read it past the title? And the answers?

Comment: I know what koenig lookup is, but I am not sure this is the answer.

Comment: Well it is. I assure you.